# jQuery OnClick Run External Page when complete update page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onclick

I know it's possible using jQuery to load/run an external web page. In the past I've used something like:

```
$.ajax({ url : 'test.php'})
```

What's I'm looking to do now is when a user click the 'GO' button an external PHP is called. Whilst it's running the main page should show 'please wait' and once the external script has finished the main page should update to show completed.

The php page I'm calling is actually running a shell script and I get no feedback from it. However the page runs and completes fine.

Is there anyway I can tell if it's still running and then update the main page ?

I'd be grateful if some one could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

UPDATE based on answer below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#update").click(function() {
$("#status").html("<p>Please Wait!</p>");
$.ajax({ url : 'test.php' }).done(function() { $("#status").html("Completed"); });
    });

});
</script>

<span id="status"><span>
<input type="button" id="update" value="Check for Update" />
```

Comment: You would need to return _something_ from the external page, even if it just an empty page with Status 200 response. How long goes the script take to complete? Can you return something at the end, ideally a flag stating 'complete' or 'true/false' so your ajax could deal with it appropriately

Comment: Wrap your ``$.ajax`` with a ``$('#go-elm').on('click')``. You'll want to read up on the ``done()`` callback to know when the page is ajax is done being sent to the browser: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: To check if your ajax request is completed, you can use `ajaxComplete` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take an example:

you have this html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatecheck()
{
//Shows Please Wait in Status
$("#status").html("<p>Please Wait!</p>");
$.ajax({ url : 'test.php'})
.done(function() {
//Hides Status
$("#status").html("");
}
</script>

<span id="status"><span>
<input type="button" onclick="updatecheck()" value="Check for Update" />
```

`.done` will be triggered when the ajax request will be completed and it will hide the value.

In case you want to show completed instead of hiding value just use:

```
$("#status").html("Completed");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url:"test.php",
  beforeSend: function(){
    //show the loading!
  },
  success:function(){
    //hide the loading
  }
})
```

you should also make shure that your server side script runs correctly! and response with a status ok!